# Calculating a to power b (a^b) in shell script

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting. 
I was doing some math problem in shell script, i found almost all the calculations involving math except a to power b (a^b).

can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong here?

```
echo -n "enter op1 opr op2: "
read op1 opr op2

power()
{
    value = $op2
    a = $op1
    if [ $value -eq o ]
    then 
        echo "$op1 ^ $op2 = 1"
    else
        while [ $value -ne 1 ]
        do 
        a = expr $a \* $op1
        value =`expr $value - 1`
        done
        echo "$op1 ^ $op2 = $a"
    fi  
}

while [ "$op1" != "quit" ]
do
    if [ $opr == "+" ]
    then
        echo "  result: $op1 + $op2 = "`expr $op1 + $op2` 
    elif [ $opr == "-" ]
    then
        echo "  result: $op1 - $op2 = "`expr $op1 - $op2` 
    elif [ $opr == "/" ]
    then
            echo "  result: $op1 / $op2 = "`expr $op1 / $op2` 
    elif [ $opr == "x" ]
    then
        echo "  result: $op1 x $op2 = "`expr $op1 \* $op2`
    elif [ $opr == "^" ]
        then
        echo "  result: $op1 ^ $op2 = "`expr $op1 ^ $op2`
        else
        echo "  invalid operator ( + - x / )"
fi

echo -n "enter op1 opr op2: "
read op1 opr op2
done
```

Comment: Are you looking to write it for integral operands only, or floating-point operands as well?

Comment: Use [`bc`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/mathc.html#BCREF): `echo "2^3" | bc`

Comment: or ```echo "  result: $op1 ^ $op2 = $(($op1**$op2))"``` but it doesnt handle floating-point as @wchargin pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

`bc` is part of POSIX:

```
echo "2 ^ 3" | bc
```

prints `8`

See `man bc` for details.

Comment: @aragaer That would work in a shell that supports here-strings, such as `ksh`, `zsh` and `bash`, but not standard `sh`.

Answer (score 3):

*There are multiple problems with your code. I'll address the specific question about exponentiation (`a ^ b`).*

> can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong here?

[`expr`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?expr) does not support exponentiation:

```
$ expr 2 + 2
4
$ expr 2 \* 2
4
$ expr 2 ^ 2
expr: syntax error
```

There are many ways to work around this. For example if you have Python, you could use it as a powerful calculator (both floating-point and arbitrary-precision integer):

```
$ python -c 'print(2 ** 3)'
8
```

Comment: (The downvote was me. Sorry for not commenting earlier; I assumed that as soon as I downvoted, you would take another look, realize instantly that your answer had nothing to do with the question, and fix it. Since you seemingly *haven't* had that realization yet, hopefully this comment will prod you to have it!)

Comment: @ruakh: It's pretty clear that there are multiple problems with the code. However the question reads to me as being specifically about exponentiation. With this in mind, I don't consider the downvote to be justified (but is of course your choice to make).

Comment: The thing is, it seems to me that the OP is already aware that `expr` doesn't support involution; that's why (s)he's created this whole `power` function to try to implement it.

Comment: (Actually, "nothing to do with the question" is an exaggeration: the OP's code does actually use `expr ... ^ ...`. I'm assuming that the OP already knows that that doesn't work, but that's an assumption on my part, and it's not the only way to read the question. I'll retract my downvote.)

Answer (score 1):

Just by inspection, I see a number of errors; for example:

- The command `value = $op2` runs the command `value` with the arguments `=` and whatever `$op2` expands to. I assume that what you intended to do was set the variable `value` to the value of `op2`; for that, you need to write `value=$op2` (with no spaces).
- In `a = expr $a \* $op1`, you never actually run the `expr` command (it's just a value on the right-hand-side). I guess you meant to write `` a=`expr $a '*' $op1` ``?
- In `[ $value -eq o ]`, `-eq` tests for numeric equality, but `o` is not a number. I guess you meant to write `0`?

In general, you're going to need to break your code apart into small pieces and test them individually. You can't just write a whole script, with lots of parts you're not sure about, and then expect to debug it all at once.

---

**Edited to add:** I left out one of the biggest problems, which is that you wrote this whole `power` function to perform involution, but then you don't actually use it; this:

```
echo "  result: $op1 ^ $op2 = "`expr $op1 ^ $op2`
```

needs to be this:

```
echo "  result: $op1 ^ $op2 = "`power`
```

Comment: thanks for the errors. still I think I am doing something wrong here. My limited knowledge of shell disables me from finding that out. can you please suggest what is wrong here?

Comment: @MikeTaylor: Your limited knowledge of shell prevents you from *already knowing* what's wrong. It certainly doesn't prevent you from *figuring out* what's wrong!

Comment: this is totally different that java

Answer (score 1):

Code for m power n

```
echo Enter number and power
read n
read m
pow 1
for((i=1;i<$m;i++))
do
pow=$(($pow*$n))
done
echo #pow
```

Answer (score 0):

echo "Enter base"
read base
echo "Enter Power"
read power
a=$base

for (( i=$power; i>1; i-- ))
do
base=`expr $base \* $a`
done
echo "$a power of $power

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow. Please add an explanation to improve the quality of this answer. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)